# Routing an XML web service onto azure using SSIS

Tags: c#, sql, azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

we have a webservice call to export the contract header data from Source to external system.The web service will extract all the contract workspaces information  based on the date range in the CSV file format. I tried to use an http connector in azure to move that web service data onto azure which was unsuccessful. Now trying to do it with SSIS to call that service and route it onto azure. I need a step by step procedure on how can we achieve this. There is a BOT process in Azure but, we are trying to implement it using SSIS. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: maybe to try with logic app? you can execute data factory pipelines with logic app also, and you have http trigger there.

Comment: Hi Dragan, Thanks for responding. The thing here is we are using source as script component and destination as the script component, we need to write a C# to get that base 64 string as the data is encoded in that string. Decode that and get is as a zip file then unzip and upload to blob.

Comment: It has a Header file exported from the service. Contains a base64-encoded ZIP file with a CSV file. The CSV file contains rows of header fields

Comment: @DraganB can you let me know that process of how to do it with logic apps? I dont know how to write JSON in Request Body JSON Schema

Comment: sorry for late respond, can you explain to me what you want to accomplish? If you want to take a header from data you can try with get metadata activity in data factory, if you want to trigger data factory process on http request you can use a logic app, etc. 
If you can explain to me your flow, I can give you my feedback then.

Comment: Trigger a data factory process on http request using logic app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's straightforward, create a logic app based on HTTP trigger, then you have data factory connector in connectors.

[This](http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/matthow/post/Using-ADF-V2-Activities-in-Logic-Apps) is a basic scenario how you can do that. After submitting logic app it will generate URL for HTTP request.

There is 3 Data Factory actions in Logic app:

- Cancel a pipeline run
- Create a pipeline run (this will create a new pipeline)
- Get a pipeline run (this will run existing pipeline)

I guess you need to choose *Get a pipeline run*

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you @Dragan. I sorted it out. We had a big complication here. There were zip lifes inside that service which were encoded with base 64. And we needed to decode it, get the zip files. What all we did was used the logic apps to call the service, get the base 64 string(XML) Convert XML to JSON and route that base64 to Table on azure. Then create an ssis package get that base64 from Azure dev database, convert that base 64 to byte, loads the zip from byte and then load onto BLOB. Now, I have to unzip those files in DF using copy data and load those unzipped csv files onto azure final tables.

Comment: @Sam glad if you resolve it. Do you know how to unzip files with DF?

Comment: No, I am still searching for it. I am not getting a clear explanation on that. Can you explain me clearly on how to unzip them and how to load them onto azure table?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#compression-support

here you have an example of how to copy and unzip files from {*} to Azure SQL. Try it out and let me know if you need assistance. Are you working with ADF V2 or V1?

Comment: Working with ADF V2

Comment: check this, declare compression type on sink side and follow this guide from msdn 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compress-codecs#compression-support

Comment: Cool! Thank you. Will let you know if I have any questions once I start working on that tomorow.

Comment: No problemo man. If you see this helpful, please upwote my answer :)